# combine these tasks in just one python file, possible?

Tags: gpio, python

I have 2 tasks that are executed separately and each has its own python file.

One task is to monitor the gpio. What it does is count how many times a button is pressed. I have to run this forever and used linux command nohup to run this in background.

I have another python file that simply displays a menu. Like below.

> Please choose:
>   1. Display button press count.
>   2. Reset button press counter.
>   3. Quit.

I'm just starting to learn python. So my question now is how can I make this into one file or 1 single task if possible. Simply put, how can I display the menu and do the monitoring at the same time.

Pardon me if this is terribly the wrong way of doing things. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to include your existing Python programmes before you can hope to gain any constructive advice...

Comment: @SlySven, no, I just need the idea... Already got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Here is an exemple:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class Thread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self, ):
        Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    #Do stuff


class Thread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    #Do other stuff


thread_1 = Thread1()  # initialise
thread_2 = Thread2()  # initialise
thread_1.start()
time.sleep(1)
thread_2.start()
```

The only problem I have when I use thread is to kill the program. I found a solution (not the best), the solution is to kill the thread with:
    `pkill -f -9 programName.py`

Comment: Thanks! Can threading share variables or should I use something like database? I need the `counter` to be visible in both tasks... one to update and the other to read from it.

Comment: Yes, You can use a global variable in other functions by declaring it as `global` in each function that assigns to it. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/8978675) link for exemple